# Closed form for Complex Infinite Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to find a closed form solution (one that does not involve a summation) for 
$\sum_{j=0}^\infty (j+1) \left(\frac{(x-i)(y+i)}{(x+i)(y-i)} \right)^j$ where $x, y$ are complex numbers.  I have tried using a generating function but I'm uncomfortable with series manipulations when they are complex.

Answer (score 2):

The formula for a geometric series is valid for complex $x$ where $|x| < 1$. Let 
$$r = \frac{(x-i)(y+i)}{(x+i)(y-i)}$$
Then for $|r| < 1$, I think we have
$$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} r^j = \frac{1}{1-r}$$
$$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} r^{j+1} = \frac{r}{1-r}$$
$$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(j+1)r^j = \frac{1}{(1-r)^2}$$
And your closed form is
$$\frac{1}{\Big(1-\frac{(x-i)(y+i)}{(x+i)(y-i)}\Big)^2}$$
But be careful to make sure $\Big|\frac{(x-i)(y+i)}{(x+i)(y-i)}\Big| < 1$ (also as a side note, if $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ then the magnitude is $1$, so they have to be complex)